# Can everything have a vague identity?

Tags: identity, mereology, vagueness

> For any objects, it is traditionally assumed that that either the
> objects are identical or distinct, and not both. Vague identity is a
> view that rejects this absoluteness of identity. Its proponents claim
> that it is possible that it be vague whether or not some objects are
> identical. Some discussions run this together with Parsons' view that
> it is possible it be indeterminate whether or not objects are
> identical.

---

> `is an integer greater than thirty' has sharp boundaries, has no
> borderline cases, and is not susceptible to sorites paradoxes.

### I don't know the exact relation between vagueness and vague identity

I am wondering if "vague identity" means "can appear in a vague identity statement" (I don't have access to enough material to decide).

If so, can only precise things be "an integer greater than thirty", so that not everything has a vague identity?

Does that mean not everything is vague?

Comment: It seems to me quite vague. .

Comment: hmm everything @MauroALLEGRANZA ? you could be right.

Comment: We (human persons) know who we are: our identity is also "social": records, bank account, etc. Philosophers like to be "hyper-skeptical": whatever cannot be "proved" with 100% certainty, must be discarded: but they forget that 1005 certainty is simply meaningless: every proof (also mathematical ones) has a lot of previous assumptions.

Comment: yes human persons love to be evasive @MauroALLEGRANZA who cares

Comment: anyway @MauroALLEGRANZA just trying to get help with my beliefs. i am not seeking to show off being an idiot. hope this is fine

Comment: Where are those quotes from?